# trigger exec fault on non-exec page

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm looking for a way to trigger from a user written program a fault where a non-exec mmap'd page is executed leading to the kernel killing the process.

I'm not sure how I can push executable code in the allocated mmap buffer form within the actual program so it contains a valid instruction so that the termination is not SIGILL when I try to cast the memory to a function pointer to execute it causing the fault.

This is on arm64 if it makes any difference.

Thanks

Final code I used on arm64:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* change these to reflect your hardware's opcodes */
#ifdef __aarch64__
#define NOP 0xD503201F
#define RET 0xD65F0000
#else
#error Unsupported platform
#endif

void memset32(uint32_t* dst, uint32_t value, size_t size)
{
    size >>= 2;
    while (size--) {
        *dst++ = value;
    }
}

typedef int (*func_ptr)( void );

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* mmap() some anonymous memory */
    func_ptr dummy_func = mmap( NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    /* emit the address to compare to the fault address
     we should be getting later */
    fprintf( stderr, "Dummy func: %p\n", dummy_func);

    /* fill the memory with NOP opcodes */
    memset32((uint32_t *)dummy_func, NOP, 4096);

    /* put in a return just for grins */
    ((uint32_t *)dummy_func)[512] = RET;

    /* call the "function" */
    int dummy_result = dummy_func();
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the `mmap()`'d block with NOP opcodes for your hardware, then use a function pointer, and set it to the address of the `mmap()`'d block. Then use the function pointer as a function call.

Strangely enough, this C code actually executes successfully on my x86 Solaris box:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* change these to reflect your hardware's opcodes */
#define NOP 0x90
#define RET 0xC2

typedef int (*func_ptr)( void );

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    /* mmap() some anonymous memory */
    func_ptr dummy_func = mmap( NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0 );

    /* emit the address to compare to the fault address
       we should be getting later */
    fprintf( stderr, "Dummy func: %p\n", dummy_func );

    /* fill the memory with NOP opcodes */
    memset( dummy_func, NOP, 4096 );

    /* put in a return just for grins */
    ( ( char * ) dummy_func )[ 1024 ] = RET;

    /* call the "function" */
    int dummy_result = dummy_func();
    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: I'll be trying this as soon as I can if only I could find the opcode for return on arm64. I found the nop one though.